# Can't set an object in ObjC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector, nsobject

Whenever my method sets an object to **onTouchEventReceiver**, it gets lost when another method is called by another thread.

```
//In header
id onTouchEventReceiver;
SEL onTouchSelector;

- (void) setOnTouchSelector:(SEL)sel withObject:(id)obj
{
    NSLog(@"setting obj to %@",obj);
    onTouchSelector = sel;
    [self setOnTouchEventReceiver:obj];
    NSLog(@"====----- %@",onTouchEventReceiver); //That works
}

//Another thread calls this
- (void) touchEventReceived
{
    NSLog(@"firing a selector at %@ by %@",onTouchEventReceiver,self);

    //Why on earth does that happen?????

    if (onTouchEventReceiver != nil) //onTouchEventReceiver is (null)
    {
        [onTouchEventReceiver performSelector:onTouchSelector];
    }
}
```

**The code produces the following:**

```
2010-07-18 23:40:54.776 app[737:903] setting obj to <appCtl: 0x10fa00>
2010-07-18 23:40:54.787 app[737:903] ====----- <appCtl: 0x10fa00>
```

**... after the screen was touched ...**

```
Got touch event at coordinates 154 x 243 , mask : 2
2010-07-18 23:41:39.342 app[737:3b03] AALayer hit test passed : <AALayer: 0x110af0>
2010-07-18 23:41:39.348 app[737:3b03] firing a selector at (null) by <AALayer: 0x110af0>
```

Why does that happen? The code seems to be correct .

Comment: don't see all of your code, but are you sure this all happens on the same instance? could you NSLog `self` as well in setOnTouchSelector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AALayer` in your log message makes me think that it might be a subclass of `CALayer`. If this is the case, then you might easily have two separate objects. `CALayer`s get duplicated for presentation by the rendering machinery. If this is the problem, you need to subclass `-initWithLayer:` to copy your extra ivars appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think yo forgot the @property. Can you :

1/ Show me the property code

2/ Change this line to :     `NSLog(@"====----- %@",onTouchEventReceiver); //That works` to     `NSLog(@"====----- %@", [self getOnTouchEventReceiver]);` //That works